# Weird Render Issue that doesn't match Camera

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Following on from the Coffee Cup tutorial by Blender Guru, I had a go at making an insulated glass coffee cup modelled on the reference image below.

[image]

I modelled the cup, it looked fine in the Layout view, but when I hit Render, I get some really weird results. I've literally only just started using Blender this week, so I'm a complete beginner. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. See Layout View vs. Render below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using a subdivision surface modifier on your "glass". Under the modifier settings, there are 2 subdivision values - one for render and one for viewport. My guess is you have the render value turned down to 0. Look at the modifier settings.

Comment: Aha. Thank you. I do have a subdivision surface and a solidified modifiers on the glass. I put the solidify first but I’m not really quite sure what difference it makes. Will check the render on the subsurface.

Comment: Ok. It turns out that Viewport and Render were both set to 2. I put subdivision surface modifier above solidify and it gave a different but equally weird render.

Comment: Strange. I'm not sure then... Any chance you could upload your blend file, so I, or someone else can have a look? You can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I don't know what I did (I got rid of a hidden object and renamed the cup object), I hit render one last time, and it is now rendering properly. Sorry! I have no idea what fixed it!

Comment: It must have been the hidden object - hidden from viewport, but not the render. Glad you got it fixed.